# VIM plot function

Tags: r, subset, axis, missing-data

I am working with the VIM library to try and see the pattern of my missing data. From my original data set I made a subset as following:

```
newdata<- df[c(11,17:45)] #This makes a new dataframe with columns 11 and 17 through 45 (to get the number of column type (names(dataframe)))

newdata1<-newdata[which(df$variable1=='1' |
                         df$variable1=='2'),]    #This makes a new dataframe of df including only variable 1 = 1 and variable 1 = 2

library(VIM)
## for missing values
miss <- aggr(newdata1)
newdata1
attach(newdata1)
plot(newdata1, sortVars = FALSE,
     sortCombs = TRUE, axes = TRUE,  combined = FALSE, labels= TRUE)
```

I am having trouble with my output, I am not seeing the variables on the x-axis.

[image: missing values per variable]

I want to be able to see the names of the missing variables.

My dataframe is something like this:

```
   Result    question1    question2    question3   question4   question5 
    1         1             1            1          1            1
    1         2             1            1          2            4
    2         1             1            3          1            2
    1         1             2            1          3            1
    2         NA            1            2          2            1
    1         1             1            NA         2            2
    1         NA            NA           1          3            1
    1         1             4            1          3            1
    2         2             NA           NA         3            2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
miss <- aggr(newdata1, col=c('navyblue','red'),
                  numbers=TRUE, sortVars=TRUE,
                  labels=names(newdata1), cex.axis=.5,
                  gap=3, ylab=c("Missing data","Pattern"))
```

You can try the code such as above. Hope you can get the labels on the x-axis.